# how to populate radio button selected value in edit form in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, edit

I'm new in angular please help me. I tried a lot but failed in prepopulating the radio button selected value in the edit form.
please find the below HTML code:

HTML code:

`

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="col-sm">
  <fieldset class="form-group">``
       <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
           <label id="example-radio-group-label">Typical Service Cost Range</label>
    <mat-radio-group aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label" class="example-radio-group radio-list"
     formControlName="service_cost"><br>
      <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button radio-list"  value="Up to 10,000"> Up to 10,000  AED </mat-radio-button><br>
 <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button radio-list"  value="Up to 50,000"> Up to 50,000  AED </mat-radio-button><br>
 <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button radio-list" value="Up to 10,000"> Up to 100,000  AED </mat-radio-button><br>
 <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button radio-list" value="Up to 104,000"> Up to 1004,000  AED </mat-radio-button><br>
  
       </div>
    <div *ngIf="customerForm.controls.service_cost.invalid && (customerForm.controls.service_cost.dirty || customerForm.controls.service_cost.touched || photo_submit)"
   class="">
 <div *ngIf="customerForm.controls.service_cost.errors.required"> Please select the Services cost range </div>
 </div>
</fieldset>`
```

in js:

`this.customerForm.controls['service_cost'].setValue(data.result.service_cost);`

Answer (score 1):

There are two major errors in your code.

**First**, you've set `checked` to all the radio buttons. That means all will be checked.

**Second**, all of your radion buttons `value` is the same. Which must be unique.

So, you `mat-radio-group`'s HTML will be:

```
<mat-radio-group aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label" class="example-radio-group radio-list" formControlName="service_cost"><br>
    <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button radio-list" value="Up to 10,000"> Up to 10,000  AED </mat-radio-button><br>
    <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button radio-list" value="Up to 50,000"> Up to 50,000  AED </mat-radio-button><br>
    <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button radio-list" value="Up to 100,000"> Up to 100,000  AED </mat-radio-button><br>
    <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button radio-list" value="Up to 500,000"> Up to 500,000  AED </mat-radio-button><br>
    <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button radio-list" value="Up to 1,000,000"> Up to 1,000,000  AED </mat-radio-button><br>
</mat-radio-group>
```

And make sure that you use `[formGroup]="customerForm"` at your `form` tag.

See demo at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5wxufb?file=src/app/radio-ng-model-example.html) for full details.